# Why is it that I can not capture the new value after my button is click?

Tags: javascript

I am still pretty new to JavaScript. I have a script that will click on a next Month button and I want it to capture the new Header value. Why is it that it still capture the value before the button was click? I want to use the script to to trigger the button and for it to capture the new value as well.

I tried to use the `eventListener` and `dispatchEvent` but maybe I am not using it correctly.

```
var CalandarMonthValue = document.getElementsByClassName('CalandarMonth')[0];
let NextMonthButton = document.getElementsByClassName('NextMonthButton')[0];

function triggerChange(element){
    let changeEvent = new Event("change");
    element.dispatchEvent(changeEvent)
}

console.log("Current Month: "+ CalandarMonthValue);

NextMonthButton.click();
NextMonthButton.addEventListener("click"),()=> {
    triggerChange(CalandarMonthValue)
});

CalandarMonthValue = document.getElementsByClassName('CalandarMonth')[0];
console.log("New Month: "+ CalendarMonthValue.textContent);
```

the output I am getting is this:

```
Current Month: December
New Month: December
```

Comment: possibly due to the event handler being registered after the click

Comment: You have a closing parenthesis after the event name, so your function is outside the addEventListener and it does not work